# Eclipse CVS client: "cannot add file to non-branch tag"

Tags: eclipse, version, cvs

I have checked out a version of a project, modified some files and added a few more.

Is there any way of adding the changes to the same version, or is creating a new version the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have checked out a **tag** and try to commit into the **tag**, you have to create **branch** based on the **tag**, and commit into this **branch**.

Comment: I already have a branch. This branch has more versions and I have checked out one of them (a version). I am trying to work on that version and add changes to it (impossible?) OR create a different version from it.. but for both these cases, the branch should need to remain the same. Is this possible?

Comment: Versions the way you mean are just particular revisions in files.  You would need to add the file to the branch, and then tag the new file with the version tag.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works for new files. But my problem is with existing files. That particular version is pretty old and some files have been modified in the meantime. Any advice for this?